# service 'image' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am following a tutorial on udemy and followed the exact steps the tutor did and wrote a docker compose file, but when I enter the command to build and run the app the following error occurs: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', service 'image' must be a mapping not a string.

I tried changing the image to image: redis:alpine instead of image: redis as mentioned on docker docs but it still gives the same error, I even tried image: 'redis'.

```
version: '3'
services:
 redis-server:
   image: redis
 node-app:
   build: .
 ports:
   - "4081:8081"
```

Comment: Please paste exact error output.

Comment: If your actual `docker-compose` file has the same indentation as in your post then it is clearly indentation problem. `node-app:` should be in the same level as `redis-server`.

Comment: I fixed the indentation but the error is now service 'ports' must be a mapping not an array.

Comment: I fixed the indentation of ports too, it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 36):

I think it's just indentation :

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis-server:
       image: redis
    node-app:
       build: .
       ports:
           - "4081:8081"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I just copy and paste some blog code and I get this error. You just saved me a lot of time! Thanks!